# Перенос строки при выводе в textView

Tags: android

В БД есть поле содержащее строки типа `слово\nслово\nслово`

Вывожу строки из этого поля в `textview`, при этом строка выводится с символами `\n`, т.е. не происходит перенос строки. Как из вывести с переносом строки?

Comment: Проверьте, не выставлен ли у вас для этого TextView в Layout'е атрибут android:singleLine="true"

Comment: нет, не выставлен

Comment: А если добавить эту строку `textView.setText(text.replace("\\n", "\n"));`
перенос строки происходит?

Comment: Если указать такую строку напрямую в `TextView`, то у меня проблема не воспроизводится. У вас сохранется проблема при хардкорном выводе такой строки в ваше `TextView`?

Comment: заработало.. я тоже пытался заменить символ \n на \\n только местами перепутал что на что заменить и не срабатывало.